# SwiftUI pre fill TextField from ViewModel

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, combine

I have a view model called `UserService`. Let's says that this stores all the user data and it's automatically updated when the data is changed in Firestore.

Then I have a View with a `TextField` called `phone`. This is used as an input to get the user phone number.

This view has a ViewModel also and this vm contains the `@Published var phone: String = ""` property which the TextField uses.

**The problem is that other than using this `TextField` to update the value I want it to also show the current value coming from `UserService`.**

I do not know how to pass this data from `UserService` to `TestViewModel`. If a put `UserService` inside `TestViewModel` the property wont be updated in real time since vm inside vm is not supported yet in SwiftUI. Right now i have ended up with two separate properties. the `phone` inside  `UserService` and the `phone` inside `TestViewModel`.

I thought of manually updating `phone` inside on init() (`TestViewModel`) but I'm not sure if thats the correct way to do it since I have a other properties other than `phone`

How can I achieve smth like this?

```
struct User: Identifiable, Codable {
    var phone: String
}


class UserService: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: User?
}


struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var testViewModel = TestViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject var userService: UserService
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("PHONE NUMBER")) {
                TextField("Phone number", text: $testViewModel.phone)
            }
        }
    }
}


class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var phone: String = ""

    init() {
        prefillForm()
    }
    
    func prefillForm() {
      //
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible approach is to initialise `vm` in `onAppear` and sync back to `userSettings` in `onChange`, like

```
Section(header: Text("PHONE NUMBER")) {
    TextField("Phone number", text: $testViewModel.phone)
        .onAppear {
            testViewModel.phone = userService.user?.phone ?? ""
        }
        .onChange(of: testViewModel.phone) { value in
            userService.user?.phone = value
        }
}
```